# smurf attack using C#

Tags: c#, denial-of-service

I am currently developing an application for my Networks Security project, which involves launching of smurf attack using C#. Smurf attack includes that u send a packet to any server (let's say yahoo,google) but in your destination u place the ip address of any victim(which the attacker wants to attack . So with this all the host (yahoo ,google) sends response to the victim, if large number of requests are sent then  it can also cause denial of service. Now the problem is implementing it in C#, because C# don't allow u to change the packet header, if i use the TcpClient class i can only give the IP + Port of the host to connect but i cannot change anything in the packet header (it automatically places your ip in the destination of the packet), i just want to know that is there any way
that i can access and change the packet header,?

Is there any library which can help me in this context?

Comment: If **you** want to ask how to construct a nefarious web attack and claim it to be "for school", **you** might want to use language that would be appropriate *in school*.

Comment: can u share your smurf attack c# project ??? i need it for a university project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Pcap.Net library](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/) allows you to [construct your own packets](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pcap.Net%20Tutorial%20-%20Sending%20Packets&referringTitle=Pcap.Net%20User%20Guide) through `SendPacket()`. The example in the second link shows you how to construct and send ICMP Echo packets.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ori!!
i have explored Pcap.NEt and it is very helpful for my project....
:)

Comment: Glad to help. Please make sure that whatever code you write is used for auditing rather than harming people. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks Ori, i am just doing this project as part of studies; actually it's my project for Course Networks Security.. I will not harm anyone... Don't worry...  :)

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that raw sockets are not supported by newer versions of Windows due to the potential of DOS'ing innocent victims: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548(VS.85).aspx

If the OS allows it, you should be able to use raw sockets from C# to do so without any external libraries (of course, you will have to craft the IP header manually).

E.g. see here: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/249594-c-raw-sockets

Comment: How do you translate "only members of the Administrators group can create sockets of type SOCK_RAW on Windows 2000 and later." into "not supported"?

Comment: I've been referring to the paragraph starting with "On Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2), and Windows XP with Service Pack 3 (SP3), the ability to send traffic over raw sockets has been restricted in several ways".